# Combine multiple older commits into one

Tags: git

I currently have a branch which looks like the following (with `A` being the most recent commit and `K` being the oldest, many months ago)

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-J-K   (branch-alpha)
```

What I would like to do is replace commits `D-G` with `Z` so that the resulting branch looks like so

```
A-B-C-Z-H-J-K   (branch-alpha)
```

All the examples I could find refer to combining the most recent commits, but I want to keep the most recent 3 commits are they are. I want to combine commits number 4, 5, 6, 7, all into one. How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1. Make a complete copy of your repository with your working folder, and then **experiment on the copy**! 2. Try this command: `git rebase -i C`, then select the "squash" command for commits E, F, G, you get to reword the commit afterwards with all the commit messages to form Z.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: There's no reason to make a copy of the repository, a new branch is safe enough. (and even without one, the original branch can be retrieved from the reflog)

Comment: I disagree. Not because it is strictly necessary, but my experience here on Stack Overflow is that people will follow blindly every git command people suggest, including reset --hard, force push and what not. I do not intend to be held even remotely responsible for someone messing up their repository more than they already have.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Fair enough. It's just that in some cases a complete copy might be expensive (for large repositories), and might make it annoying to resume later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming `A - K` is the last 10 commits, you can run the command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

which opens the "interactive" => `-i` command prompt editor (with the last 10 commits) looking something like:

```
pick a2260e9 A
pick ff5e839 B
pick 965d9ea C
pick b09f2ae D
pick d1c9f15 E
pick 93309a9 F
pick e17d8fd G
pick d10491b H
pick 110c55f J
pick b57bc16 K

# Rebase ae65653..b57bc16 onto ae65653
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

you then change the following lines from `pick` to `s` for "squash"

```
pick a2260e9 A
pick ff5e839 B
pick 965d9ea C
pick b09f2ae D
s d1c9f15 E
s 93309a9 F
s e17d8fd G
pick d10491b H
pick 110c55f J
pick b57bc16 K
```

Save the file. On the next screen it will ask you about the commit message. Add a `#` on every line which has not got a `#` yet. That will then be treated as a comment. Add one line with only a `Z` that will then be the commit message for the squashed commits

**the end result looks like:**

```
a2260e9 A
ff5e839 B
965d9ea C
38e9fab Z
553c8c7 H
23acc30 J
143561a K
```